# Jquery play framework avoid dual submission

Tags: jquery, playframework

I have a Jquery which submits during on complete and because of that the submission happens twice. Is there a way to avoid the same?

Following is the code snippet.

---

My routes for Claim loading looks like this.

```
# Claim Loading for Historical Claims
GET     /claimLoading            controllers.ClaimLoading.form
POST    /claimLoading            controllers.ClaimLoading.submit
```

---

In my controller the submit happens as shown.

```
/**
 * Handle form submission.
 */
def submit = Action { implicit request =>
claimLoadingForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  // Form has errors, redisplay it
  errors => {
    Logger.info("Some error occurred before calling the service")
    BadRequest(html.claimloading.form(errors))
  },
  claimLoading => {
    // Invoke the LoadCSVorXML2Mongo service from here
    claimsLoadingService.loadCSVOrXMLClaimToDatabase(claimLoading.claimLoadingPath)

    val resultSummary  = claimsLoadingService.retrieveSummaryInfo
    // We got a valid ClaimLoading value, display the summary
    Ok(html.claimloading.summary(claimLoading, Json.prettyPrint(resultSummary)))
  }

)
}
```

---

Jquery call from the button click is >>>>

/views/claimloading/form.scala.html

```
<input type="button" class="btn primary" id="claimsLoadButton"  value="Invoke Claim Loading">
```

---

Jquery in the form.scala under claimloading is >>>>

```
<script type="text/javascript"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#claimsLoadButton").click(function () {
        createLoadingModal();
        showLoader(true);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/claimLoading",
            type: "POST",
           data: $("#claimLoadingForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            dataType:"json",
            success: function (data) {
                showLoader(false);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            },
            complete: function (data) {

                submitClaimsLoading();
            }
        });
    });
});

function submitClaimsLoading()
{
    $("#claimLoadingForm").submit();
    showLoader(false);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [event.preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop form submission on button click.

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //add this here
    $("#claimsLoadButton").click(function () {
        createLoadingModal();
        showLoader(true);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/claimLoading",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#claimLoadingForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                showLoader(false);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
            complete: function (data) {

                submitClaimsLoading();
            }
        });
    });
});
```